# How can I add / in my string as a paramter in django url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I have land numbers such as '171/20' , '23','34/112/1' , etc. on passing these as a parameter I should be able to fetch info about them. The problem is I can't do something like we do normally. because it will be like

```
localhost:8000/171/20
```

which is not what I want exactly.

Comment: can elaborate the problem a bit more, unable to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters instead. Pass them to the URL.

Like this: `localhost:8000?ln=171/20`

Comment: And then in the view function, you can use `request.GET["ln"]` to get the value, i.e. "171/20" in this example.